# Can someone help me resolve this issue for Flask

Tags: python, html, mysql, database, flask

I have tried an assignment taken from internet for displaying data from flask to hmtl form.
But the issue here is I'am getting two errors:-
1) The HTML file rendered in flask is not found.
2) The SQL table and columns are not resolved.

I have tried resolving this issues with many solution through internet. 
I tried it on Pycharm and using MariaDB Connector, the test connection was successful.
 Can Someone solve it for me?

The flask code is as follows :-

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
# Database connection info
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ''

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'LibraryDB'

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

mysql = MySQL()

mysql.init_app(app)

conn = mysql.connect()

cursor = conn.cursor()

@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def search():

    if request.method == "POST":

        book = request.form['book']

        # search by author or book

        cursor.execute("SELECT name, author from book WHERE name LIKE %s OR author LIKE %s", (book,book))

        conn.commit()

        data = cursor.fetchall()

        # all in the search box will return all the tuples

        if len(data) == 0 and book == 'all':

            cursor.execute("SELECT name, author from Book")

            conn.commit()

            data = cursor.fetchall()

        return render_template('search.html', data=data)

    return render_template('search.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.debug = True

    app.run()
```

My HTML code is as follows :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="utf-8">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/index.css" type="text/css">
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Library</h1>
        <form class="example" method="post" action=""
         style="margin:auto;max-width:600px">
            <label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search by author or book, or all to see all the data" name="book">
            </label>
            <button type="submit">Search<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
        <p></p>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
        {% for item in data %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{item[0]}} by {{item[1]}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Am fine with CSS so let's not bother that

Comment: You need to specify the exact error like a line the error occurs or share a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the data is getting parsed into your query and is it fetching results from the table? You can check that by using the following code:

```
print(cursor._executed)
```

after cursor.execute()

and for error number 1: 
I will say please verify the name of the HTML file.

p.s there is no need to use `conn.commit()` as it is advisable to use only when you are creating a record, updating a record or deleting a record from the table, so you can go ahead and delete that part.

*Let me know if this helps you or not.*